# Strange behavior for find if pattern following -name is not quoted

Tags: find

It is so strange that sometimes the following pattern of -name in find could unexpectedly search all the corresponding filenames successfully.
By rights, it could only search one corresponding filename in the current directory via the shell parse (not find utility that without quotation).

```
find /tmp -type f -name *.txt

/tmp/amp_iostat.txt
/tmp/awrrpt_1_7950_7973.txt
/tmp/oplanlog/osys/2014-07-01-12-26-28/log.txt
/tmp/oplanlog/osys/2014-07-01-13-15-33/log.txt
/tmp/oplanlog/osys/2014-07-01-13-17-58/log.txt
/tmp/oplanlog/osys/2014-07-01-13-30-27/log.txt
/tmp/oplanlog/osys/2016-10-27-19-38-50/log.txt
/tmp/pms2_20170427.txt
/tmp/pmsdb1_20170622.txt
/tmp/pmssh1_20160728.txt
/tmp/pmssh1_20160831.txt
/tmp/pmssh1_20161227.txt
/tmp/pmssh1_20170328.txt
/tmp/pmssh1_20170523.txt
/tmp/pmssh1_20170727.txt
/tmp/pmssh1_20170822.txt
/tmp/pmssh2_20170328.txt
/tmp/pmssh_20170119.txt
/tmp/pmssh_20170220.txt
/tmp/sgpms_20140717_1736_summary.txt
/tmp/sgpms_20140717_1736_trace.txt
/tmp/sgpms_20140717_1737_summary.txt
/tmp/sgpms_20140717_1737_trace.txt
/tmp/sgpms_20140717_1739_summary.txt
/tmp/sgpms_20140717_1739_trace.txt
/tmp/sgpms_20140717_1743_summary.txt
/tmp/sgpms_20140717_1743_trace.txt
/tmp/sgpms_20140717_1749_summary.txt
/tmp/sgpms_20140717_1749_trace.txt
/tmp/sgpms_20140717_1751_summary.txt
/tmp/sgpms_20140717_1751_trace.txt
```

---

```
find /tmp -type f -name *.txt|wc -l
      31
```

Comment: You're in an empty directory/one with no `.txt` files. Is that the question?

Comment: Yes, there is just by chance no any  .txt files under the current directory(/)！

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without any quoting `*.txt` is subject to [pathname expansion (aka filename expansion)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion). This happens in the *current working directory* (CWD). If the CWD contains any files with extension 'txt' then before calling `find` the shell replaces the `*.txt` parameter with the matching filenames and your command becomes something like this:

```
find /tmp -type f -name file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt ...
```

There are at least three results you can then get depending on whether the expansion returns...

- *...multiple files:* you will get an error
- *...one file and its name matches a filename in the path(s) you are running `find` against:* the `-name` test will match just that one file
- *...one file and it matches no files in the searched path(s):* `-name` will match nothing

On the other hand if the CWD does *not* contain any txt files then `*.txt` is passed to `find` and it behaves exactly the same as if you quoted it.

Moral: when using `find` always put quotes around patterns that contain globs unless you actually want the pathname expansion to occur (rarely would you see this done intentionally for the `-name` option).

Comment: Yes, you are right！   I have already tested & verified the result！
But why the find utility still always starts to search files from the current directory(/)  regardless of specific searching path(/tmp)

Comment: Pathname expansion doesn't have anything to do with `find`. It's a function of the shell and it happens before `find` runs. So the expansion occurs against your CWD. But `find` will still be operating against the path you pass to it. You should not be seeing something different.

Comment: In fact, I mean that the find utility should be able to avoid & filtrate this unnecessary disturb from the current directory,  or why not！？

Comment: Because, like I said, this all happens before `find` starts...it has no way of knowing that you passed it `*.txt`. I made a small update to my answer to point out that shell replaces the param.

Comment: Yes, thanks to your wonderful explanations！！