# How to rm files starting with a digit

Tags: command-line, rm

I have following files starting with a digit.

```
$ echo [0-9]*
1001tracklistsIcon.svelte 1passwordIcon.svelte 3mIcon.svelte 42Icon.svelte 4chanIcon.svelte 4dIcon.svelte 500pxIcon.svelte
```

And I'd like to `rm` them.

I tried this but not working:

```
$ find . -type f -name [0-9]*  -exec rm {} \;
find: 1passwordIcon.svelte: unknown primary or operator
```

How can I do it?

Comment: See [Strange behavior for find if pattern following -name is not quoted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/408336/strange-behavior-for-find-if-pattern-following-name-is-not-quoted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your pattern in "":

```
$ find . -type f -name "[0-9]*"  -exec rm {} \;
```

Otherwise your shell will replace it with the matching file names *before* running find.

Comment: Unless of course he does not want files beginning with a digit in subdirectories removed. In which case a simple `rm [0-9]*` will work.